# How to create an association between user and schedule?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to create an association which allows users following the schedule they are interesting.

Here is my model:

```
class Scheduleship < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :schedule
end
```

and Controller:

```
class ScheduleshipsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @scheduleship = current_user.scheduleships.build(schedule_id: params[:id])
        if @scheduleship.save
         flash[:notice] = "Susses Added ."
         redirect_to Posts_url
        end
    end
end
```

The corresponding of DB table has two data `:user_id` and `:schedule_id`.

And I use `link_to` method to create an association between user and schedule

```
 <%= link_to 'add to schedule', {controller: 'scheduleships',
 action: 'create',
 user_id: current_user.id,
 schedule_id: post.id }, method: :post, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" %>
```

But it didn't create association.

the `:schedule_id => nil`

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the schedules id as `schedule_id` from the view, but querying `params[:id]`, which is `nil`, while saving.

Try the following in your controller:

```
def create
    @scheduleship = current_user.scheduleships.build(schedule_id: params[:schedule_id])

    if @scheduleship.save
        flash[:notice] = "Added successful."
        redirect_to Posts_url
    end
end
```

Also, I feel `Scheduleship` is a terrible name for the association. I probably would go with `UserSchedule`.

Comment: I established association successful,but  I can't display post.id on the view in `user#show`,  `<%= d.schedule.title %>` is `nil:class`